# UL or DIV vertical scrollbar

Tags: css

I have problem with vertical scrollbar on my page. I have lot of items inside ul inside div, I tried with overflow:auto in style for div but it doesn't help. How to add scrollbar vertical to ul or div ?

```
<div id="content">
<p>some text</p>
<ul>
<li>text</li>
.....
<li>text</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Extra scrollbars in a webpage make it less accessible, and more cumbersome to use. I'm not saying that they're not useful; just make sure you've thought long and hard about how users will interact with the page before adding scroll bars where they're not needed.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You need to define height of ul or your div and set overflow equals to auto as below:

```
<ul style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
```

Comment: Is there any chance that scrollbar be uinvisible ?

Comment: what do you mean about uninvisible? you may play by changing height with min-height or max-height to get your desired output.

Comment: No, my scrollbar iz blue when appears. I wonder is there any chance that be invisible, like on android phone ?

Comment: I see.. I think you need javascript plugin to do that. Take a look at the http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: I've heard it doesn't work on IPAD/Androd... could somebody prove or deny it?

Comment: For some reason this breaks flexbox column.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set a height on the DIV. Otherwise it will keep expanding indefinitely.

Comment: The OP asked for vertical scrollbar.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo: That's what this answer is about.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it is not eligible to set height to pixel values.
However, it is possible to show vertical scrollbar through setting height of div to `100%` and `overflow` to `auto`.

Let me show an example:

```
<div id="content" style="height: 100%; overflow: auto">
  <p>some text</p>
  <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    .....
    <li>text</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

this works for me :

```
<ul style="height: 100%; overflow: auto"
  <li>text1</li>
  ....
  <li>text100</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same as [@StepUp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50141994/3025856) from a few years ago?

Comment: not the same .. but its works for me , thx