# How to get scroll bar for dynamic list view in jquery / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have one list view which will get values dynamically from DB. How can I set scroll bar for the list view, If it has more than 3 values int it? Is this possible ? How to do that..

My code is as follows,

HTML code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
    <li value="Select Location">Select Location</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting values dynamically from DB with following code,

```
$("#select-choice").on('change', function(event) {
    $("#locationList").empty();
    var catg = this.value;
    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "MYDB"});
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select Location from Locationlog WHERE Category = '"+catg+"';", [],     function (tx, res) {
            var optionheading = '<li value="Select Location">Select Location</li>';
            $("#locationList").append(optionheading);
            for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                var opt  = '<li value="';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '">';
                opt += res.rows.item(i).Location;
                opt += '</li>';
                $("#locationList").append(opt);
            }
            $("#locationList").listview('refresh');
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Try this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamically-generated-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeated question:
[UL or DIV vertical scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102832/ul-or-div-vertical-scrollbar)

Define a width and height when you have more than 3 items:

```
<ul style="width: 300px; height: 200px; overflow: auto">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Anyway, tell us what kind of list view are you using (jquery ui control i mean)
Perhaps Jquery ui Mobile?